# How to assert huge array which should not contain more than two objects with specific values with chai

Tags: typescript, chai

I want to assert the result of a function which returns a huge array of objects(40k) like this:

`[{id:232, local:'en-US'},{id:233, local:'en-US'}...]`

using the [Chai Assertion Library](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/).

I expect the array to have not more than 2 members with the same id, and if there are two the `local` field should not be the same.

I even don't know where to start since all the examples in the documentation are rather simple.

My first try was to assert when there are 2 objects in the array with same `id` and same `local` like so:

```
   const fu = [{id:3,local:'d'},{id:3,local:'d'},{id:4,local:'d'},{id:4,local:'t'},{id:5,local:'d'}]
    fu.forEach(f=>{
        expect(fu).not.include.members([{id:f.id, local:f.local},{id:f.id, local:f.local}])
    });
```

But even this does not work since it passes even if the first two objects are the same.

Comment: I cannot find any uniqueness related function in chai. But I think there is a trick that you can aggregate a simpler result yourself, and then assert that. In your case, you can build your own isUnique boolean, and than expect it to be false.

Comment: yea I think something like this should work. However can I somehow still use chai for checking? Basically using expect but without stopping the testrunner?
I also don't know why the example above passes... this is still weird.